# JavaScript function splice not running on certain web pages

Tags: javascript, function, greasemonkey

So I'm writing some code for a grease-monkey bot but on the site the bot is for the JavaScript function splice() is not recognized and does absolutely nothing when run. The array I'm using consists of about 100 or so different elements all got from the web page and I then need to sort them removing certain elements if they have a certain style as in... (Variables were initialized earlier)

```
list = document.getElementById("raffles-list").children;
while (a > list.length) {
 if (list[a].style != "") {
  list.splice(a, 1);
  a++;
 }
}
```

I know it is nothing to do with my computer as I was able to splice on other web sites so is there a way that I can remove the element without splice or is there a way I can get it to work on the website?

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: TypeError: list.splice is not a function

Comment: <element>.children returns a HTMLCollection, not an array.  There is no splice method for a HTMLCollection.  Are you trying to remove elements from the page with this code?

Comment: Another problem (assuming that splice worked, which it doesn't) is that if you do remove an element from list, your a++ assignment will skip the next element (because list shrinks, the number of elements is reduced, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens, because `Node.children` returns `HTMLCollection`, that is no an array and doesn't have splice method - [for more information look MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).

You can use `Array.prototype.splice.call(list, a, 1)`, this must do the thing.

Comment: Thanks for telling me why it didn't work and I actually found a way to avoid it... with a return true or return false but your answer helped me get there

Answer (score 0):

To remove an item of HTMLCollection use remove function:

```
list[a].remove();
```

**Below is a code snippet to demo the function, you'll need to adjust your logic accordingly.**

```js
var list = document.getElementById("somelist").children;
 
//not knowing what your initial a value, setting it to zero
var a =0;
var output = document.getElementById("output");
//go through the list
while (list.length>0) {
    //get an item
    var item = list.item(0);
    output.innerHTML+="Removed: " + item.innerHTML+"<br/>";
    list[0].remove();
}
```

```html
<ul id="somelist">
    <li style='a'>what</li>
    <li style='b'>is</li>
    <li style=''>this</li>
</ul>
<p>Output:</p>
<div id="output"></div>
```